# Are there security risks in giving user "Apache" maximum permissions?

Tags: apache, security

This is more of a sever question but I have cron jobs that create files by Apache. When it writes files it does so with user "Apache" so now the file is owned by that user. If I go into FTP with my username then it assigns ownership and permission to my username so next time the cron job runs it tries to delete the created file and create a new one but I get a "permission denied" error.

The one solutions I can think of is to give user Apache the ability to edit and delete files that belong to other users. Or I could change the Apache config file to use "root" or another user that has the ability to edit and delete files owned by other users. If I do so, would that create a security issue since Apache pretty much would have root access to the rest of the server?

Would changing Apache to use user "Root" be safe?

Thank you for your guidance.

PS If the best thing to do is give user "Apache" higher access could you give me the ssh commands to use in Centos 7? Perhaps with a command to do it for all files in folder /vhosts and below?